# How to make numbers show as hh:mm (duration, not time of day)

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

I'm using an Access query and dumping the data into Excel. Each row contains a value showing how much time as certain task should take, but it simply gives me the number of minutes (e.g. `123`).

Is it possible to either:

1. Use an Excel formula to convert the sum of these numbers into `hh:mm`; or
2. Convert the figures directly in Access?

Every time I convert it with the built-in Excel options, it gives me a time-of-day instead of duration.

Comment: A figure? Do you actually mean the integer value `123`? That would mean 123 days. What would the expected result look like?

Comment: it's currently giving me the number of minutes displayed as an integer. Ideally, instead of 123, it would show up as 2:03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXT(A1/1440,"[H]:MM")
```

Another option would be to just calculate the devide and custom format `B1` with `[H]:MM`

If I misunderstood and you interested in the time of day you can use:

```
=TIME(0,A1,0)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since Access does not support the `[H]:MM` formatting code to show elapsed time, if you wanted to format the result in Access, you would need to use something like:

```
[Minutes]\60 & ":" & Format([Minutes] Mod 60,"00")
```

Where `[Minutes]` is the name of your integer-valued field containing the number of minutes elapsed.